# Sending array and other data with a single ajax request with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I've got a java servlet that receives all the requests from my pages and returns some data as json. I'm quite sure the servlet is ok but i don't understand where I fail in the script. The script has an action parameter that is a string that I need in the servlet to understand what to do and in this case i need also to pass 2 arrays (1 array of int and 1 of String). The servlet tells me the json of the array is malformed.
js script:

```
$(document).ready(
$.ajax({
        url: "Controller",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action: "load",
               subjects: getSubjects(),
               days: getDays()
              },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            //do stuff

            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    }));
```

Json parsing is done with gson:

```
Integer[] days = gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("days"), Integer[].class);
String[] subjects = gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("subjects"), String[].class);
```

i tried with both arrays empty and it works but if one or both contains something it doesn't. 
P.s: i create the arrays in the functions and return them
P.s.2: the elements are added to the array with a push
P.s.3: i searched a lot on internet but in the newest version of jquery a lot of stuff changed and past answers doesn't work.

EDIT: I tried with JSON.stringify(getSubjects) and JSON.stringify(getDays) but it didn't work

Thanks for the attention :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `getSubjects()` and `getDays()` functions return an array while you want a JSON string. You can produce a valid JSON string using `JSON.stringify()`.

When dealing with server requests be sure the check the network tab of your browser's developer tools (Click F12 to open them on browsers like Firefox and Chrome).

```
/*
Wrong Way - Passing array as a parameter
In this way you send the parameters:

  action: load
  subjects[]: 1
  subjects[]: 2
  subjects[]: 3
  days[]: 1
  days[]: 2
  days[]: 3

*/

$.ajax({
    url: "Controller",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        action: "load",
        subjects: [1, 2, 3],
        days: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        //do stuff
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
        console.error(xhr.status, thrownError);
    }
});

/*
Correct Way - Passing JSON string as a parameter
In this way you send the parameters:

  action: load
  subjects: [1,2,3]
  days: [1,2,3]

*/
$.ajax({
    url: "Controller",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        action: "load",
        subjects: JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]),
        days: JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3])
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        //do stuff
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
        console.error(xhr.status, thrownError);
    }
});
```

*EDIT*

Full working example code:

File **Test.java**

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

// Extend HttpServlet class
@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {

    public void init() throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set response content type
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Actual logic goes here.
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Test");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Integer[] days = gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("days"), Integer[].class);
        String[] subjects = gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("subjects"), String[].class);

        // Set response content type
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Actual logic goes here.
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(
            "days : \"" + Arrays.toString(days) + "\"<br>" +
            "subjects : \"" + Arrays.toString(subjects) + "\"<br>"
        );
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // do nothing.
    }
}
```

File **text-ajax.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/Test",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: "load",
                    subjects: JSON.stringify(["a", "b", "c"]),
                    days: JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3])
                },
                /*Just to be sure*/
                contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
                    console.error(xhr.status, thrownError);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes they return array and i tried to parse the result of the functions with JSON.stringify(getSubjects()) but it didn't work

Comment: Well you can try adding `contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",` option on the ajax but this is the default, any other problem is not ajax related. Check the working example I added.

Comment: idk how now it works without i changed anything. Anyway thanks, if I can't resolve the retrieving of sucjects and days by the html I think there will be a new post by me eheh

Comment: Tomcat needs restart some times :P